# What is the difference between $\frac{1}{N}\sum\frac{y_i}{x_i}$ and $\sum\frac{\overline{y}}{\overline{x}}$

Tags: statistics

I have a data set and I was looking at the population ratio and trying to estimate it using different methods. I was expecting eq1 and eq2 to be different but was very surprised that it was by a factor of almost 3x. I was just wondering why it was so different, is it partly due to $n$ cancelling on eq2.
Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Say $x_i = i$,  $y_i = n +1 - i$, for $1 \le i \le n$. The sum $\sum_i y_i/x_i = \sum_i (n + 1 - i) / i = (n + 1) H_n - n$, $\overline{y} / \overline{x} = 1$, quite different (here $H_n = \sum_{1 \le k \le n} 1/k$ is the harmonic numbers).